# spring session good practice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I have 2 spring apps, I send requests from the First app to the second one with unirest. Something like below, as seen I am using basic auth. So far it works. I suddenly got this thought, will this create a session on each request? If so can I immediately end the session after the response is sent? I am not much willing to change the current implementation.

```
HttpRequest jsonResponse = Unirest.get(beeUrl+"/getPresentById/"+memId+"/"+role).basicAuth(bid.getPvalue(), bpwd.getPvalue()).header("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Yes, it will create a session on each request. Unless you send cookies along with each request. You can set up spring security so that the session isn't created: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html#STATELESS But if users manually would log in using basic auth - they won't like this much.

Comment: I do store some values in session when I log in, then use it in service or repo, like client Id. In this case, I should go for the alternative of storing these values in turn that would require an entire code change, is there any other way?

Comment: What if I extract jsessionid from the response and then pass it along with the further requests, does that still create a new session?

Comment: You can pass sessionid in cookies of the next queries. This way you'll be re-using previously created session. Don't forget to handle session expiration (in which case you'll have to authenticate again).